# Mouse shoulder buttons not working with Synergy

Tags: windows-7, linux, mouse, fedora, synergy

I'm using synergy to share my mouse and keyboard from my fedora 23 linux server to a Windows 7 machine, and the mouse shoulder buttons don't work (side buttons, thumb buttons, whatever you want to call them).

I need to find out how to enable them. The only info I have so far is that **xev** reports my mouse buttons as **button 8** and **button 9**. And the mouse buttons are remapped via **xmodmap** (i switched button 8 and button 9 with xmodmap so they are reversed) I tried to follow [this github thread](https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/58) on the subject. What I found was that supposedly this can be worked around by adding options to the synergy config file. Something like..

```
mousebutton(4) = mousebutton(8)
mousebutton(5) = mousebutton(9)
```

Should be able to fix it according to that thread, but I've tried various combinations without any sort of reactions from my shoulder buttons. I also tried changing mousebuttons 1-3 and noticed that their inputs didn't change either so something's fishy about this command (even if synergy doesn't report it as an error, so the options are valid, just don't seem to do anything)

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?